# FFMPEG - Drawtest not show using complex filter with muiple transparent image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am running the following command for  audio to video conversion : both images  display properly in video after  conversion but draw text not showing in video.

['-loglevel', 'error', '-y','-i', 'abc.jpg', '-i', 'logo.png', '-i', inputFile,'-filter_complex', '[1][0]scale2ref=h=ow/mdar:w=iw/4[#A logo][abc];[#A logo]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.9[#B logo transparent];[abc][#B logo transparent]overlay =0:0; [0]drawtext=text=fontfile=bold:fontsize=200:x=w-tw:y=0:fontcolor=red:text=Hundred APP','-pix_fmt','yuv420p', '-c:v','libx264','-movflags', '+faststart','-f', 'mp4',  outputFile],

Comment: Once the logo has been overlaid on the image, how do you plan to combine it with the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

['-loglevel', 'error', '-y','-i', 'abc.jpeg', '-i', 'Frame@3x.png', '-i', inputFile,'-filter_complex', '[1][0]scale2ref=h=ow/mdar:w=iw/4[#A logo][abc];[#A logo]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.9[#B logo transparent];[abc][#B logo transparent]overlay =0:0,drawtext=text=fontfile='+fonts+':fontsize=30:x=w-tw:y=0:fontcolor=white:text=Hundred APP','-c:v','libx264','-movflags', '+faststart','-f', 'mp4',  outputFile],